# Copy line and insert it in a new position with sed or awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have this file:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

I want the last line to be copied to before the first line, so I'll get the following result:

```
f
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

How can I do it in `sed` or `awk`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pure `sed`:

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;G' file.txt
```

All lines are collected in the hold space, then appended to the last line:

- `H` appends the current line to the hold space. Unfortunally this will start the hold space with a newline, so `1h` for the first line, the hold space gets overwritte with that line without preceeding newline
- `$!d` means if this is not (`!`) the last line (`$`), `d`elete the line, because we don't want to print it yet
- `G` is only executed for the last line, because for other lines the `d` stopped processing. Now all lines (first to last) we collected in the hold space get appended to the current (last) line with the `G` command and everything gets printed at the end of the script.

Answer (score 10):

With `ed`:

```
$ printf '$t0\n,p\n' | ed -s file
f
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

The `t` command in `ed` transfers/copies a line from the addressed line (here `$` for the last line) to after the line addressed by its argument (here `0`, i.e. insert before the first line).  The `,p` command prints the contents of the editing buffer (change this to `w` to write the result back into the file).

Answer (score 9):

or simply like this, without sed or other

```
tail -1 list && cat list
```

Answer (score 8):

Another `sed` alternative would be:

```
sed '$!d; r infile' infile
```

delete all lines except last, next read and output whole file.

Comment: This is the best solution, very neat and inventive.

Comment: But there is a problem: I get the text from stdin via pipe. There is no way I can use that `r infile` command.

Answer (score 3):

GNU awk:

```
awk 'ENDFILE { if(NR==FNR) print } NR!=FNR' infile{,}
```

Portable awk:

```
awk 'NR!=FNR && !f { f=1; print p } NR!=FNR; { p=$0 }' infile{,}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the file, remember the *first* line and print it *after the last line*, then re-reverse the file:

```
tac file | awk 'FNR == 1 {last=$0} {print} END {print last}' | tac
# or
tac file | sed -n '1h; p; ${x;p}' | tac
```

Comment: `tac file | sed '1h;$G'  | tac`

Answer (score 2):

Tried with below sed  command  and it worked fine too

command

```
k=`sed -n '$p' filename `
sed '1i '$k'' filename
```

output

```
f
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 tail -n1 file | xargs -I '{}' sed '1i{}' file
```

- `tail -n1` will print the last line of the file
- `xargs -I` will pass the tail output to sed
- `sed '1i` will insert the context in first line

if the output looks file, add `-i` option to sed to do inline edit

Comment: That assumes GNU `sed` and that the first line doesn't contain quotes nor backslashes and doesn't start nor end with blanks.